# scale width according to remaining space without setting parent element to flexbox?

Tags: css

Let's say you have a container with `max-width of 600px`. Now imagine the viewport is greater than `600px`, so for example `900px`. How do you set width to `600px plus 20% of the remaining space (so 20% of the 300px in this case)`?

So basically `flex-basis: 600px` and  `flex-grow: 0.2`.

the following solution works:

```
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {  
    width: calc(600px + ((100vw - 600px) * 0.2));
  }
}
```

That is because I know the full width is gonna be 100vw everytime. But what if you don't know the total width, how do you scale to grow 20% of remaining space without setting flex on parent?

Comment: I think using `100%` instead of `100vw` should work in your case.

Comment: Please post a minimal example - this includes your HTML.

Comment: @ShakyaPeiris ofcourse, how stupid of me ...

Comment: whataver the width you will have you cannot get bigger than max-width

Answer (score 0):

If i understand question correctly

```
.container { 
  width:max(600px, calc(600px + (100vw - 600px) / 5), 100vw);
}
```

and or `%` instead of `wv`, and no `@media`.

3rd param 100vw - to avoid mobile @out of screen".

> That is because I know the full width is gonna be 100vw everytime. But
> what if you don't know the total width, how do you scale to grow 20%
> of remaining space without setting flex on parent?

[Container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) not supported widely yet, but will add ability to get container width for CSS needs as `cqw`.